# Merge PHP arrays

Tags: php

How can I merge few arrays into one in the following format.

Thanks.

```
Array
(
    [apple] => 1
    [mango] => 5
    [banana] => 3
)
Array
(
    [car] => 2
    [bus] => 7
    [moto] => 8
)
Array
(
    [rain] => 14
    [snow] => 7
    [sun] => 12
)
```

New Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [apple] => 1
            [mango] => 5
            [banana] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [car] => 2
            [bus] => 7
            [moto] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rain] => 14
            [snow] => 7
            [sun] => 12
        )        

)
```

Comment: array_merge : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: @racar Not applicable for the desired result

Comment: i agree, array_merge(array($array1),array($array2)...) not really a good way to do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really very simple

```
$newArray = array($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

or more literally

```
$newArray = array(
    array('apple' => 1, 'mango' => 5, 'banana' => 3),
    array('car' => 2, 'bus' => 7, 'moto' => 8),
    array('rain' => 14, 'snow' => 7, 'sun' => 12)
);
```