# merge custom 2 array

Tags: php, arrays

halo guys. nice to meet you. i am still new in program. especially in php code. now im learning about array code. can i merge 2 array become 1.

ex : 
i vardump some parameter and the result like this

```
'list_data' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'branch_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'branch_id' => string '4' (length=1)
```

can i merge that array become like this :

```
'list_data' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string  '3' 
  1 => string  '4'
```

please help me. im so curious about this.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the `array_merge()` function?

Comment: i already used that function. but the result still same with the first one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge PHP arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236259/merge-php-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case for [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$array = [
    'list_data' => [
        [ 'branch_id' => 3],
        [ 'branch_id' => 4],
    ]
];

$array['list_data'] = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['branch_id'];
},$array['list_data']);
var_dump($array);
```

Or [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$array['list_data'] = array_column($array['list_data'], 'branch_id');
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. really appreciate.. God Bless You